# Spring Security and Custom Authentication Provider

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a custom `AuthenticationProvider` that simply returns the `Authentication` object for the `authenticate` method. What I want to do is add a role to the user when they log in. This is for demo purposes, so all I want is the user to enter a username and let them in. I need to assign them the admin role.

Comment: Very relevant tutorial: http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/937/customization-spring-security-authentication

Comment: You can just implement UserDetailService to customize your authentication process either from a database or from web service, because it is provided by an out of box AuthenticationProvider implementation: DaoAuthenticationProvider which is a conceret class of AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider and relies on UserDetailService to provide user name and password to compare them with user inputs to achieve authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are, of course, several ways to achieve that.
My preferred one is do this in a custom [`UserDetailsService`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html). The only method is [`loadUserByUsername`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html#loadUserByUsername%28java.lang.String%29), that will return an instance of [`UserDetails`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html). When you are constructing your `UserDetails`, you can add whatever [`GrantedAuthority`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html) you want.

So first, you'll declare your custom `UserDetailsService` in your application context configuration file:

```
<bean id="myCustomUDS" class="com.myapp.AppUDS" />

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
   <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myCustomUDS">
   </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

Then you write the class itself:

```
public class AppUDS implements UserDetailsService {
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        //create your concrete UserDetails
        //add your custom role (i.e. GrantedAuthority) to that object (that will be added to all users)
        //return it
    }
}
```